# Spring Boot, perform scheduled method on Heroku free plan

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

Hello I have my `Spring Boot` app deployed on Heroku free plan and main limitation here is app idling when is no used and this is the clue of this topic.

Lets say I want a code annotated with `@Scheduled` to perform every day at 3 AM but most probably my app will be idling / sleeping at this time. The question is if this method will run then and know somehow that it needs to wake up from sleeping and run a method at specific time?

If not, what workaround would you suggest?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your application would be idle at 3 AM already (Assuming that there is no interaction and app is idle). Then the scheduled code do not run at all.

As far as I remember, if there is no interaction with the application, the app will be idle after 30 min (with heroku's free plan).

I assume that your spring boot application has an endpoint. So define a logic and call the application's own endpoint in every 30 minutes. The scheduler will start working when the application is launched. Therefore you would guarantee that the application runs all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried something like ping and that was working (keeping an app alive) until the moment of exceeding working hours / month. I received then an email saying that and my app isn't working due this limitation.